# setOnClick for 100 buttons

Tags: android, button, onclick, buttonclick, onclicklistener

I have 100 buttons (from button000 to button 999). Is there any way to setOnClick for all of them? Because all button have the same function. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put them in a list, loop over the list, do what you need to do.

Comment: Use `Button` and extends it and declare setOnClick in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your buttons are inside a layout then do like this.

```
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
      v.setOnCLickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you one more question: how can I identify all of them? I define 1 button using this query: Button btn000 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn000);

Comment: if(v instanceof Button){ we have a Button }else{skip it} to be sure you set the listener on buttons only

Comment: and also may be to differentiate your these 1000 buttons with other you can use  btn000.setTag("mybutton"), so on with rest 999 button with same tag and in onClick(view v ) callback use v.getTag();

Answer (score 1):

Buddy try this way

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);    
     buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
     Button buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB); 
     buttonB.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  //etc... etc...

 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.buttonA: 
      // do something
      break;
     case R.id.buttonB:
      // do something else
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to avoid typibg that all out.

Answer (score 1):

At right now I can say easiest way in
 use button000.setOnclicklistener(this);

```
  :

  :

 button999.setOnclicklistener(this);
```

and implement Onclicklistener in this current class....

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that it's the best way for your app to create 1000 buttons, then it will be something like this:

```
Button [] my_button=new Button[1000];
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
   my_button[i]=new Button(this);
   my_button[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   my_button[i].setText("button "+i);
   ll.addView(my_button[i]);
   my_button[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         ////click event
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your buttons in an array and
Just loop the buttons and on a listener you can call the following block of code:

```
for (int i=0; i < buttonArray.length; ++i){
      buttonArray[i].onClick(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods one is you can set onClick in xml layout file by onClick method you can define the method, that should be invoked when button is clicked. This method is appropriate when you define buttons in xml.

If you are adding buttons in Activity, and if you are adding in a loop then you can do as

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   //Create and Add button
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
       public void onClick(View view)
       {
            //Operations
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all buttons have exactly same functionality then you can simple use

```
private OnClickListener mListenr=new OnClickListener(
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//Whatever you want
}

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
mButton[i].setOnClickListener(mListenr);
}
```

you can refer [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10586/12329) to see ways to implement listener.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to make Button Dynamically like

```
 Integer[] button_Ids = {R.id.btn000,R.id.btn001...............,R.id.btn999};
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
 { 
 Button btn = (Button)findViewById(button_ids[i]);
  btn.setOnClickListner(this);
  }
  @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
         {
         Toast.make(getApplicationContext,"Hello",1000).show();
         }
```